# Fetching Custom Variable Values using Piwik API

Tags: php, matomo

I am trying to use this api CustomVariables.getCustomVariablesValuesFromNameId (idSite, period, date, idSubtable, segment = '')  from piwik to fetch CustomVariable values. But there is no example for it and also how to get idsubtable value ?

Is there any way to fetch custom variable values from piwik using api ?

Any help or example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Granted - this is not easy on first sight. So here's how it works:

You can find an example for `CustomVariables.getCustomVariables` at http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=API&action=listAllAPI&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday#CustomVariables. The resulting XML contains all existing Custom Variables.

Lets take the following as an example:

```
<result>
    <row>
        <label>Forum status</label>
        <nb_visits>593</nb_visits>
        <nb_actions>1571</nb_actions>
        <max_actions>40</max_actions>
        <sum_visit_length>116860</sum_visit_length>
        <bounce_count>389</bounce_count>
        <goals>
            <row idgoal='1'>
                <nb_conversions>5</nb_conversions>
                <nb_visits_converted>5</nb_visits_converted>
                <revenue>15</revenue>
            </row>
            <row idgoal='2'>
                <nb_conversions>9</nb_conversions>
                <nb_visits_converted>9</nb_visits_converted>
                <revenue>9</revenue>
            </row>
            <row idgoal='3'>
                <nb_conversions>2</nb_conversions>
                <nb_visits_converted>2</nb_visits_converted>
                <revenue>2</revenue>
            </row>
        </goals>
        <nb_conversions>16</nb_conversions>
        <revenue>26</revenue>
        <idsubdatatable>110</idsubdatatable>
    </row>
</result>
```

The `<label>` in this case stands for the key of the custom variable. The included metrics such as `nb_visits`, `nb_actions`, etc. are summed values for that specific custom variable. In order to get the values of the `Forum status` custom variable you need to use the value of `idsubdatatable` as the `idSubtable` parameter.

This results in the following URL: http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=API&method=CustomVariables.getCustomVariablesValuesFromNameId&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday&format=xml&idSubtable=110&token_auth=anonymous

Calling this URL will yield something like the following result:

```
<result>
    <row>
        <label>Anonymous</label>
        <nb_visits>544</nb_visits>
        <nb_actions>1185</nb_actions>
        <max_actions>38</max_actions>
        <sum_visit_length>83459</sum_visit_length>
        <bounce_count>380</bounce_count>
        <goals>
            <row idgoal='1'>
                <nb_conversions>5</nb_conversions>
                <nb_visits_converted>5</nb_visits_converted>
                <revenue>15</revenue>
            </row>
            <row idgoal='2'>
                <nb_conversions>9</nb_conversions>
                <nb_visits_converted>9</nb_visits_converted>
                <revenue>9</revenue>
            </row>
        </goals>
        <nb_conversions>14</nb_conversions>
        <revenue>24</revenue>
    </row>
    <row>
        <label>LoggedIn user</label>
        <nb_visits>49</nb_visits>
        <nb_actions>386</nb_actions>
        <max_actions>40</max_actions>
        <sum_visit_length>33401</sum_visit_length>
        <bounce_count>9</bounce_count>
        <goals>
            <row idgoal='3'>
                <nb_conversions>2</nb_conversions>
                <nb_visits_converted>2</nb_visits_converted>
                <revenue>2</revenue>
            </row>
        </goals>
        <nb_conversions>2</nb_conversions>
        <revenue>2</revenue>
    </row>
</result>
```

Each row's `<label>` contains a value for the `Forum status` custom variable and the metrics for that value.